# .htaccess rewrite removing letters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/296-large_default/james-bond.jpg
```

and I need to be rewritten as:

```
http://www.example.com/img/p/2/9/6/296.jpg
```

At the moment I was using this rule but somehow I'm having issues, any clue why is this happening?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Where is `%{ENV:REWRITEBASE}` coming from? (But that's not necessary in per-directory `.htaccess` files.) Are the URLs always of the exact form in your example, ie. 3 digits, hyphen, text, slash, filename? Your regex pattern doesn't seem to match this at all and introduces _optional_ parts?

Answer (score 1):

To internally rewrite from a URL of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/296-large_default/james-bond.jpg
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/img/p/2/9/6/296.jpg
```

try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d)(\d)(\d)-[\w-]+/[\w-]+\.jpg$ img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
```

This assumes the "id" (eg. `296`) is always 3 digits. There is no need to prefix the `RewriteRule` *substitution* with a URL-path in per-directory `.htaccess` files. (There is no environment variable called "REWRITEBASE" unless you have explicitly set this somewhere.)